# Getting peak memory (heap and stack) of short running program in linux

Tags: linux, memory

I made a C program which runs about a few milli seconds.

And I want to know that how much (stack and heap) memory is required to run the program.

I used Valgrind (massif), but it only measures the memory periodically.

How can I get it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is in C or C++ you might be able to use getrusage() which returns you various statistics about memory and time usage of your process.

Not all platforms support this though and will return 0 values for the memory-use options.

Instead you can look at the virtual file created in /proc/[pid]/statm (where [pid] is replaced by your process id. You can obtain this from getpid()).

This file will look like a text file with 7 integers. You are probably most interested in the first (all memory use) and sixth (data memory use) numbers in this file

Answer (score 0):

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v /path/to/your/program
```

Comment: I think that 'maximum resident set size' in the result does not provide exact 'heap and stack' size. Am I wrong?

Comment: Please provide more detail in your answer. Please explain how this command will provide the needed information.